# Dotfile management with bare git repo - question about gitignore

Tags: git, git-bare, dotfiles

This is based on https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles.

I don't understand this part: `echo ".cfg" >> .gitignore`

It seems to be adding the dotfiles folder (in this case .cfg/) to ~/.gitignore (home directory). Why? It says it's to avoid recursion. However, that step is not listed when setting up your dotfiles folder/repo for the first time. It's only included when installing on another machine. Why is it necessary on every machine except the first? Was it a missed step in setup, or is it actually unnecessary on subsequent installs, or is it for some reason required when installing but not during initial setup?

Comment: It is inconsistent, yes. It's not necessary on any machine under one condition: that you don't (accidentally or on purpose) try to `config add .cfg` or equivalent (e.g., `config add .??*` would accidentally-or-on-purpose try to config add `.cfg`). He doesn't in his initial setup, and if you also don't, ever, then you never need the `.gitignore` entry.

Comment: I suspect, but cannot confirm since I am not the author of the article, that he did the setup somewhere as an experiment, then used the setup instructions to set up his "real" system, after which he tossed the setup and hence never noticed the inconsistency.